# Ajuda Unity RogueLike

Tags: unity3d, unity-5

O compilador do Unity está apresentado este erro ao implementar o controle do Player.

> Assets/Scripts/Player.cs(58,33): error CS0115:
>   `Player.AttemptMove(int, int)' is marked as an override but no
>   suitable method found to override

Código:

```
"protected override void AttemptMove <T> (int xDir, int yDir)
    {

        food--;

        base.AttemptMove <T> ( xDir, yDir);

        RaycastHit2D hit;



    CheckIfGameOver ();

    GameManager.instance.playerTurn = false;

    }"
```

Answer (score 0):

O erro diz que não há nenhum método a ser sobrescrito com esse nome em classes superiores ou se existe esse método eles não estão marcados como [virtual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/9fkccyh4.aspx) ou [abstract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/sf985hc5.aspx). Não sei qual a derivação da função dessa classe e qual a estrutura das outras classes na hierarquia em questão, você teria de prover mais informações. De uma olhada nos [Tutoriais](https://unity3d.com/pt/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting) no site da Unity.